# How to check if record exists, if not insert

Tags: mysql, if-statement, insert, exists

I'm making a blog site and I need to check if a tag exists before inserting the tag into the tblTag

This is what I'm trying:

```
 $var_sqlTagsCheck = "IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblTag t WHERE t.tagName = '$var_tagCollectInsert'))
 BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO tblTag
 SET tagName = '$var_tagCollectInsert'
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO tblTag (tagId, tagName) VALUES ('', '$var_tagCollectInsert'))
 END
 ";
```

But is not working correctly, can anybody lend me some assistance here?? Where am i going wrong, this seems fairly straight forward SQL.

Comment: What exactly is happening/messages?

Comment: Define 'not working correctly'. In general the solution is to use unique indexes, attempt the insert regardless, and catch the duplicate key error. Not to look first and then do the insert.

Comment: It doesn't check to see if the tag exists, it doesn't work. Ie my sql statement is wrong. It give me an error message I have setup.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the *EXISTS* predicate in the *WHERE* clause:

```
 INSERT INTO tblTag (tagId, tagName)
 SELECT '', '$var_tagCollectInsert'
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblTag t
                  WHERE t.tagName = '$var_tagCollectInsert'));
```

The general form of MySQL's *INSERT INTO* is:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

Comment: hmm still comming up with same error. I tried what you said `code` $var_sqlTagsCheck = "INSERT INTO tblTag(tagName) 
SELECT 'hey'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblTag WHERE tagName = 'hey')"; `code`

Comment: Performance Tips: don't select * from TableName inseted of try Select 1 From TableName

Answer (score 0):

Is the tagId a primary key? If yes, you need not to insert '' or a null value to it. If not try setting it as a primary key and enable its auto incerement so you just need to supply for the tagName  I'm pretty sure it really is straight forward. So you should just check if all insert items have values or available for the insert query.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm finding your answer confusing, I don't have a lot of experience in this area. Are you say I need to check if the SELECT statement returns false or true

Comment: nah. you should set your tagId as a primary key. that's the true essence of primary keys right? in the code that you have submitted, you are trying to insert a value to the tagId which we shouldn't do since it should be set as a primary key. then after setting it as a primary key. 

try changingthis line:


INSERT INTO tblTag (tagId, tagName) VALUES ('', '$var_tagCollectInsert'))


into this:

INSERT INTO tblTag (tagName) VALUES ('$var_tagCollectInsert'))

Comment: My primary key for the tblTag is tagId, if you look at my code, I actually leave the value of tagId blank allowing it auto increment. the adjustment in code will not make any difference to my problem, but thanks for your advice